# How to use mysql2 0.3.16 with Ruby 1.9.3? (uninitialized constant Mysql2::Client::SECURE_CONNECTION)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mysql2, ruby-1.9.3

I'm trying to set up my local dev environment to match my team's. I can't upgrade Ruby/Rails/mysql2 (for the time being).

I know my local MySQL config is good (enough?) because I can create a new Rails project and run it just fine. I'm getting the same error if I run `rake db:create` or `rails s` or even start IRB and run `require 'mysql2'`.

I've googled the hell out of this. I was initially using MariaDB as my MySQL implementation locally, so I thought that might be screwing with the mysql2 gem. So I ripped out MariaDB and finally got MySQL 5.6 working (another team version we're locked into at the moment). After successfully upgrading to MySQL 5.6, I'm confident that's 100% not the issue.

I would expect if I had the wrong password for it to complain about the config somehow, but it's always the same.

```
uninitialized constant Mysql2::Client::SECURE_CONNECTION
```

Ruby (RVM): ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13 revision 48407) [x86_64-linux]
Mysql2: 0.3.16

There have been some other version-related struggles, but nothing this strong.  The only thing I've encountered that I haven't actually tried is building the mysql2 gem locally.

I would expect `require 'mysql2'` to at least load the gem.  Neither Rails nor Rake will work with the gem at all. It's almost like it's missing some internal file.

Comment: SO spam-filtered a huge, full-bodied post I made, so I had to pare it down to even get it to go through.  [Here's the full post](https://gist.github.com/bhollan/42f93f7a9981f698f3ff4167fbfe67aa) if there's anything missing you're looking for (Gemfile, Error details, etc.).

Comment: You're going to need to find a historical version of `mysql2` that works with your ancient version of Ruby. 1.9 is completely cut off from all support now. If you're running it in production you likely have serious security problems, so I'd recommend getting off that version as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

following as discussion about this error in official gem, you should update version as

From

```
gem 'mysql2', '0.3.16'
```

to

```
gem 'mysql2', '0.3.17'
```

if you still met an error after you update version to `0.3.17`, i think that you should update to `0.2.24`

https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/603

Comment: Apparently the restrictions on having our dev environments identical were mostly imagined.  My teammate had me update to `0.3.21` and we're past this issue for the moment.

My next task will be to convince upper management that it's worth the hassle of updating to a version of Ruby that's supported.